# Single.zip with Completable

Tags: rx-java

Here is my question: I have some singles and want to zip them. But I only want the zip function to be called after a Completable has completed. Also I want to subscribe to all singles and the Completable at the same time. (So no `completable.andThen(Single.zip(...)`)

Here is an example of what I'm doing now:

```
Single<T1> s1 = …;
Single<T2> s2 = …;
Single<T3> s3 = …;
Completable c = …;

Single.zip(s1, s2, s3, c.andThen(Single.just("")), (a, b, c, ignore) -> {
// All singles have emitted an item and c is completed
 …
})
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `toSingleDefault` when converting from `Completable` to `Single`:

```
Single<T1> s1 = …;
Single<T2> s2 = …;
Single<T3> s3 = …;
Completable c = …;

Single.zip(s1, s2, s3, c.toSingleDefault(""), (a, b, c, ignore) -> {
// All singles have emitted an item and c is completed
…
})
```

Comment: `toSingleDefault` very nice!